# How To Create A Voice Chat application ( SIP Protocol )

Tags: c++, qt, chat, sip

I need to create a voice chat application .
My preference is to use QT to develop client program as well as the server.
The Clients are identified by a particular no.
So when each client try to communicate with other client's , they should first get the connection details for the client to which it needs to be connected from the server.
Server has a database , which stores the client's connection details ..

When i searched in Google i found that [SIP Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_Initiation_Protocol) can be used for this purpose.
Can anyone give me some idea , how to use this sip protocol in this scenario , as well as what all tools i can use along with QT to code this easily ..

I don't have much idea about sip..

Comment: Did you find the solution? I'm finding a solution for cross-platform and I tried many libraries on Windows but failed because of building is not easy/updated or the document is not good support.

Answer (score 1):

Just take a look at one of the [existing applications](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_SIP_software#Free_and_open_source_license_2).

Comment: I Checked some of them , but i didnt got any idea , how its sending voice packets, as well as how the server co-ordinates the client..

can anyone pls give me a  detailed description..

Comment: You need to learn more about SIP protocol. Then you can pick any open source implementation and use it for your app. It's not a trivial task to implement SIP.

Comment: @tsurko Is some library available for SIP that can be integrated with QT + Mingw

Comment: Any C/C++ implementation should do the job. I can't recommend you any specific library but I've heard that this one is decent: http://sofia-sip.sourceforge.net/ , so I think you can start your research from there.